# AsyncTask's doInBackground blocks locationManager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, location

I'd like to find the user's location **only once**, and show a ProgressDialog (PD) until the location is not known.

I'm using an AsyncTask, in the `onPreExecute()` the PD is shown, and the `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);` is called. Because finding the position using the GPS may take a long time, in the `doInBackground()` I check if the location is available by calling `listener.isLocationAvailable()`.

After replacing the while loop with a `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {...}` loop, the output is the next:

```
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
I/System.out: cycling
```

100 times...

```
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
I/System.out: 65.9667, -18.5333
```

(displayed 100x after 100x cycling when the onLocationChanged(Location location) is called)

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
 private class PositioningTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    Context context = TransportActivity.this;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    TransportLocationListener listener;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private boolean gpsEnabled;
    private boolean networkEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TransportActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading position, please wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new TransportLocationListener();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String position = "";
        try{
            while (true){
                if (listener.isLocationAvailable()) {
                    Location location = listener.getLocation();
                    position = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
                    }
                    System.out.println("POSITION: " + position);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("cycling");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and the TransportLocationListener:

```
public class TransportLocationListener implements LocationListener {
private Location location = null;
private Boolean available = false;

public boolean isLocationAvailable() {
    return  available;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;

    available = true;

    System.out.println(location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> AsyncTask's doInBackground blocks locationManager

I suppose your problem is that you get a constant stream of location updates?

Your request with this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

is to receive location updates with `minTime` equal to 0, and `minDistance` equal to 0. This means that 'onLocationChanged' will get called even if no change in location has been done. Change this to 1000 and 0.1f to make `onLocationChanged` beeing called less frequently with real new values.

Comment: I've tried, the result is: "cycling" is displayed 100x, but the location is only once (because the devices position has not changed)

Comment: @Alex and whats wrong with that result, you dont get POSITION in output?

Comment: You also should move all this location grant permission code before calling  your AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't get POSITION output. Moved the location grant permission before calling the AsyncTask, problem still exists.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible but you might have a data race in your code. You might want to add synchronization. Like inside your listener update `available`  and `location` inside synchronized(this) { ... } block, then read it in asynctask also in such block - like synchronized(listener) { if (listener.isLocationAvailable()) { .... } }

Comment: Another hint,inside your listener change `Boolean` to `boolean` and make it `volatile` - like - `volatile boolean available` the same for location - make it volatile.

Comment: Still not works, I think this is a conceptual problem. I'm going to re-think the solution...